# Loading multiple images from database onto to the webpage

Tags: image, base64

I am actually working on a web page which is similar to the amazon shop view in vuejs.

So far, I have made multiple calls to get multiple images for each item which is really not a good idea since I have delays in response and conversion of encoding and rendering of the webpage does not happen as desired.

Is it any alternative or suggestion for this use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first, your question is mostly about best practices in fetching images from server and not for Vue.js

I would suggest to move to different topics of stack overflow.
Nevertheless I would suggest you, to perform any conversion of encoding in server, or even better, use media servers that are best solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks, I am not in control of the server calls so changes can not be made on that side.